# Terraform constantly forces recreation of aws_iam_server_certificate resource

Tags: ssl-certificate, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```sh
✦ ➜ terraform --version                       
Terraform v0.12.28
+ provider.aws v2.60.0
+ provider.kubernetes v1.11.3
+ provider.local v1.4.0
+ provider.null v2.1.2
+ provider.random v2.2.1
+ provider.template v2.1.2
```

Just put 2 new files for SSL certificate

```
  # module.ssl-certificate.aws_iam_server_certificate.cert must be replaced
+/- resource "aws_iam_server_certificate" "cert" {
      ~ arn               = "arn:aws:iam::XXX:server-certificate/xxx-ssl-certxxx" -> (known after apply)
      ~ certificate_body  = "721e444119806928d19ef830740057c52580ba71" -> "cd6882dff1edb0223a20fe5f1c2b4b594f07526f" # forces replacement
      - certificate_chain = "7e85cb3e40dff5a9f83ff75576d71fd98fdfdd89" -> null # forces replacement
      ~ id                = "XXX" -> (known after apply)
      ~ name              = "XXX-ssl-cert20200716210119477600000001" -> (known after apply)
        name_prefix       = "XXX-ssl-cert"
        path              = "/"
        private_key       = (sensitive value)
    }
```

And each time I run `terraform apply` I always asked to "replace" the certificate. Each time a new one is created.

Files (crt, key) are not changing

**/main.tf**

```
module "ssl-certificate" {
  source = "./modules/certificates"
  certificate = {
    name        = "xxx-ssl-cert"
    body        = file("assets/ssl/_.xxx.com/xxx.crt")
    private_key = file("assets/ssl/_.xxx.com/xxx.key")
  }
  team        = var.team
  project     = var.project
  component   = ""
  environment = var.environment
  tags        = module.project_config.tags
}
```

**/modules/certificates/main.tf**

```
resource "aws_iam_server_certificate" "cert" {
  name_prefix      = var.certificate.name
  certificate_body = var.certificate.body
  private_key      = var.certificate.private_key

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

What is wrong? Prior to this I had self-signed cert, and never had this behavior. Added new certs - and started to get these "recreate" required plans in **apply**.

#### Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know about this resource type in particular but a typical reason for this sort of behavior is when the remote API does some sort of normalization of what you submit that the provider isn't aware of, which then causes the provider to treat it as drift instead of normalization. If that certificate body value is PEM-encoded then my first guesses would be: maybe you are using different line endings than the server is using, or maybe you have the base64 data wrapped at a different number of columns than the server, or maybe you have a trailing newline and the server doesn't.

Comment: Unfortunately the provider seems to be obscuring the actual value by hashing it, so it's difficult to see exactly what's going on through the Terraform plan, but you could perhaps debug by fetching this value directly from the underlying API and ensuring that what you have in your file is character-for-character identical (including control characters) to what the server returned.

Comment: I just found [AWS provider issue #1215](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/1215) which seems to cover the same behavior you are seeing, and somebody there seems to have confirmed my guess above that it's caused by the wrapping of the base64 data. They had to dynamically re-wrap it because the certificate was dynamically issued in their case, but since yours is a static file you could perhaps just manually re-wrap it to 64 characters per line.

Comment: Thank you Martin - I will try!

Comment: I just had this issue and it seems to have been caused by the local cert files having DOS line endings. Running `dos2unix` on the files thus solved the issue here.

Comment: You can check if there is there are "^M$" at the end of lines by running `cat -vet myfile.crt`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use lifecycle for ignore_changes.

```
Example:   lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [certificate_body]
  }
```

Comment: Yes I did that, but the question - is why the body is always changing although not a single byte changed in my local file. So there must be something remote?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent terraform from recreating certificate when certificate contents don't change,

1. Move certificate chain contents from "certificate_body" to "certificate_chain" terraform argument inside "aws_iam_server_certificate" resource &
2. Ensure line endings in certificate_body & certificate_contents are same as actual(for my use case, line endings in cert was LF)

Answer (score 0):

As [@beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62943524/terraform-constantly-forces-recreation-of-aws-iam-server-certificate-resource#comment112753730_62943524) mentioned, the solution is to run `dos2unix` command on your cert file in order to convert it from DOS to UNIX format, especially the end of line char.